# How can I make a copy of char** in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am having trouble understanding the concept of pointers in C. I have an array of pointers to character strings,

```
char ** args;
```

and I want to copy args to another array of pointers to character strings.

```
char ** args2;
```

I tried doing,

```
args2 = args;
```

but when I manipulate args2, I also manipulate args. I know this is because of the fact that the arrays are pointers. Also, if I run a for loop,

```
// by the time I get to the for loop
// args holds {"string1", "string2", "string3"}
// args2 = NULL;
for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++){
    args2[i] = args[i];
}
```

I get a segmentation fault error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to allocate space first!

Comment: Copying a pointer doesn't make a copy of the string it points to. You need to allocate space for the copy, then use `strcpy()`.

Comment: `strcpy` is harder than needs to be used here.

Comment: When you set `args2` to the value of `args`, you basically let these pointers point to the same memory. What you probably want is to allocate as much memory as `args` to `args2` then use `strcpy()` to copy each string.

Comment: Imagine you stand on a cross road and there is a set of street signs all saying "Ice cream shop" and point in various directions. Were you now cloning each of the signs and to load them on a truck. How much more space would the truck need to carry both the signs and their clones? After the cloning of the signs, how many ice cream shops are there? How does that relate to cloning the whole area once (shops and signs)?

Comment: Arrays and pointers are different. Remembering this will help to avoid problems like you are having. `args` and `args2` are pointers, not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate space for `args2` first! Even when you do that, don't forget that you'll still just be copying pointers to the original strings, so if you modify the strings in `args2`, the original strings are the ones being being modified.

You probably want something like:

```
i = 0;
while (args[i] != NULL)
    i++;

args2 = malloc(i * sizeof *args2);

for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    args2[i] = strdup(args[i]);
}
```

Which both allocates memory for the pointers in `arg2` and also duplicates all of the original strings. Add one to `i` before the second loop and set `args2[i]` to `NULL` after the second loop if you want to have a `NULL` terminated array like you started with.

Comment: Note that `strdup` is non-standard, some other method might be needed depending on specific implementation. For instance one may use something like `args2[i] = malloc(strlen(args[i]) + 1)`, then `strcpy(args2[i], args[i])`.

Comment: Yes, if you don't have strdup, that's equivalent.

Comment: Not totally complete with showing how to free the new memory.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `char**` as a pointer of pointers. Each element of it is another pointer, which points to a string (basically you have an array of strings).

Assuming you have a `char** args2`. If you do:

```
for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++){
     args2[i] = args[i];
}
```

You copy the value of each pointer from args to args2. It is the same thing as saying:

```
char *a = "abc";
char *b; // allocate memory
b = a;
```

Or, in order to copy strings you need to copy their content, not just the pointer to the first element. So, you need to use something like `strcpy`. Note that in order for this to work, you also need to allocate memory for `args2`, which I omit here.

```
for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++){
    strcpy(args2[i], args[i]);
}
```

Also, you might want to add the NULL terminator of args:

```
args2[i] = NULL;
```

In order to allocate memory, you need to know the size of the `args` array. Assume `args` has n element. Then, the memory allocation for `args2` could be done as following (I also add the copying part):

```
// Allocate memory for n pointers to char
char **args2 = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++){
    // For each pointer of args 2, allocate memory to store the
    // correspondent string of args, including the NUL.
    args2 = malloc(strlen(args[i] + 1));
    strcpy(args2[i], args[i]);
}
```

You might want to consider using a static char matrix at the beginning that handles memory allocation, in order to facilitate learning.